# how to lazy load library modules in angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I have created a library project in angular with module named SigninModule. I build it and published it to NPM. Now I want to use that library in my current project and lazy loading of SigninModule failed.

here is the piece of code from routing module that failed

```
{
   path: 'signin',
   loadChildren: () => import('hub-auth/lib/signin/signin.module').then(m => m.SigninModule)
}
```

error message

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app-routing.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hub-auth/lib/signin/signin.module' in 'D:\git\generic-admin-portal\src\app'
```

I did some research on this and found a workaround to get rid of this by writing a wrapper module, but in my case that too wont work as wrapper module wont have that SiginComponent.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Did you installed your `SigninModule` module before importing it. like npm install SigninModule....

Comment: @Manoj yes i did.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify whether `'hub-auth/lib/signin/signin.module'` path is correct. If you have `hub-auth` directory in the same place with `app-routing.module.ts`, please change it to `'./hub-auth/lib/signin/signin.module'`